# Python-ldap search: Size Limit Exceeded

Tags: python, ldap, python-ldap

I'm using the python-ldap library to connect to our LDAP server and run queries.  The issue I'm running into is that despite setting a size limit on the search, I keep getting SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED errors on any query that would return too many results.  I know that the query itself is working because I will get a result if the query returns a small subset of users.  Even if I set the size limit to something absurd, like 1, I'll still get a SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED on those bigger queries.  I've pasted a generic version of my query below.  Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong here?

```
result = self.ldap.search_ext_s(self.base, self.scope, '(personFirstMiddle=<value>*)', sizelimit=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a Python3 implementation that I came up with after heavily editing what I found [here](https://blog.ls-al.com/python-ldap-query-active-directory/) and in the [official documentation](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html). At the time of writing this it works with the pip3 package [python-ldap](https://pypi.org/project/python-ldap/) version 3.2.0.

```
def get_list_of_ldap_users():
    hostname = "google.com"
    username = "username_here"
    password = "password_here"
    base = "dc=google,dc=com"

    print(f"Connecting to the LDAP server at '{hostname}'...")
    connect = ldap.initialize(f"ldap://{hostname}")
    connect.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    connect.simple_bind_s(username, password)
    connect=ldap_server
    search_flt = "(personFirstMiddle=<value>*)" # get all users with a specific middle name
    page_size = 500 # how many users to search for in each page, this depends on the server maximum setting (default is 1000)
    searchreq_attrlist=["cn", "sn", "name", "userPrincipalName"] # change these to the attributes you care about
    req_ctrl = SimplePagedResultsControl(criticality=True, size=page_size, cookie='')
    msgid = connect.search_ext(base=base, scope=ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filterstr=search_flt, attrlist=searchreq_attrlist, serverctrls=[req_ctrl])

    total_results = []
    pages = 0
    while True: # loop over all of the pages using the same cookie, otherwise the search will fail
        pages += 1
        rtype, rdata, rmsgid, serverctrls = connect.result3(msgid)
        for user in rdata:
            total_results.append(user)

        pctrls = [c for c in serverctrls if c.controlType == SimplePagedResultsControl.controlType]
        if pctrls:
            if pctrls[0].cookie: # Copy cookie from response control to request control
                req_ctrl.cookie = pctrls[0].cookie
                msgid = connect.search_ext(base=base, scope=ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filterstr=search_flt, attrlist=searchreq_attrlist, serverctrls=[req_ctrl])
            else:
                break
        else:
            break
    return total_results
```

This will return a list of all users but you can edit it as required to return what you want without hitting the `SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED` issue :)

Answer (score 1):

When the LDAP client requests a size-limit, that is called a 'client-requested' size limit. A client-requested size limit cannot override the size-limit set by the server. The server may set a size-limit for the server as a whole, for a particular authorization identity, or for other reasons - whichever the case, the client may not override the server size limit. The search request may have to be issued in multiple parts using the `simple paged results` control or the `virtual list view` control.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong. Also the tip with simple paged results for circumventing a server-side limit only works with MS AD.