# python-ldap: Retrieve only a few entries from LDAP search

Tags: ldap, python-ldap

I wish to mimic the `ldapsearch -z` flag behavior of retrieving only a specific amount of entries from LDAP using [python-ldap](https://pypi.org/project/python-ldap/).

However, it keeps failing with the exception `SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED`.

There are multiple links where the problem is reported, but the suggested solution doesn't seem to work

[Python-ldap search: Size Limit Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11640187/python-ldap-search-size-limit-exceeded)

[LDAP: ldap.SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378142/ldap-ldap-sizelimit-exceeded/3378226#3378226)

I am using `search_ext_s()` with `sizelimit` parameter set to 1, which I am sure is not more than the server limit

**On Wireshark, I see that 1 entry is returned and the server raises `SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED`. This is the same as `ldapsearch -z` behavior**

But the following line raises an exception and I don't know how to retrieve the returned entry

```
conn.search_ext_s(<base>,ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'(cn=demo_user*)',['dn'],sizelimit=1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the discussion in the comments, **this is how I achieved it:**

```
import ldap

# These are not mandatory, I just have a habit
# of setting against Microsoft Active Directory

ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
ldap.set_option(ldap.OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3)

conn = ldap.initialize('ldap://<SERVER-IP>')
conn.simple_bind(<username>, <password>)

# Using async search version
ldap_result_id = conn.search_ext(<base-dn>, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,
                                 <filter>, [desired-attrs],
                                 sizelimit=<your-desired-sizelimit>)
result_set = []
try:
  while 1:
    result_type, result_data = conn.result(ldap_result_id, 0)
    if (result_data == []):
      break
    else:
      # Handle the singular entry anyway you wish.
      # I am appending here
      if result_type == ldap.RES_SEARCH_ENTRY:
        result_set.append(result_data)
except ldap.SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED:
  print 'Hitting sizelimit'

print result_set
```

**Sample Output:**

```
# My server has about 500 entries for 'demo_user' - 1,2,3 etc.
# My filter is '(cn=demo_user*)', attrs = ['cn'] with sizelimit of 5

$ python ldap_sizelimit.py

Hitting sizelimit
[[('CN=demo_user0,OU=DemoUsers,DC=ad,DC=local', {'cn': ['demo_user0']})], 
[('CN=demo_user1,OU=DemoUsers,DC=ad,DC=local', {'cn': ['demo_user1']})], 
[('CN=demo_user10,OU=DemoUsers,DC=ad,DC=local', {'cn': ['demo_user10']})], 
[('CN=demo_user100,OU=DemoUsers,DC=ad,DC=local', {'cn': ['demo_user100']})], 
[('CN=demo_user101,OU=DemoUsers,DC=ad,DC=local', {'cn': ['demo_user101']})]]
```

You may use play around with more srv controls to sort these etc. but I think the basic idea is conveyed ;)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution only works because you have under 1000 users. There's a default search limit of 1000 users so if you have more than that this will fail :(

Comment: @Josh Does `ldapsearch -z` in that case ?

Comment: The default search limit is still applied depending on the server configuration, so if you type `ldapsearch -z 5000` but the server is set to 500 you can only get 500 results at a time unfortunately.

Comment: @JoshCorreia Yes, I know that `ldapsearch -z` fails too, after displaying the allowed number of entries. The goal of the question, if you read it carefully was mimic `ldapsearch -z` behavior. Without the proposed solution, python-ldap won't display anything and would fail blatantly. And the solution also mentions that you may play with more srv controls for your needs. So basically, the accepted answer was accomplishing what was desired

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the async search method [LDAPObject.search_ext()](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.search_ext) and separate collect the results with [LDAPObject.result()](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html#ldap.LDAPObject.result) until the exception `ldap.SIZELIMIT_EXCEEDED` is raised.

Comment: Does that mean that the `search_ext_s(sizelimit)` is broken ?

Comment: It simply means that it does not what you expected.

Comment: Can you please explain what that parameter does in `search_ext_s` ? From the document I could only understand this much. But google hits also return pages where you have suggested `async` approach. In my case the LDAP server is always MS AD. The issue is that in large environments, my ldap query fails with TIMEOUT so I wish to retrieve only limited number of entries with SIZELIMIT

Comment: From your proposed solution, it seems that I should collect the results till server raises an error ? But I don't want to do that, just need server to return a small number of search results. How can I achieve that ?

Comment: It simply does not work how you wish it to work, no matter how often you ask for it. But feel free to ignore my answer.

Comment: I am not ignoring your answer. I just wanted to understand what `sizelimit` parameter in search_ext_s() does ? Is the method, you provided here https://github.com/python-ldap/python-ldap/blob/master/Demo/Lib/ldap/async/sizelimit.py a good way to handle this ?

Comment: I'm not the maintainer of python-ldap anymore. You could use this example code. But module `ldap.async` was renamed to [ldap.asyncsearch](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap-async.html)

Comment: With the async `search_ext()` I can still use `sizelimit`, right ?

Comment: Yes, `search_ext()` does have key-word argument `sizelimit`.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52465289/7487335) works if you are searching for less users than specified by the server's sizelimit, but will fail if you wish to gather more than that (the default for AD is 1000 users).

Here's a Python3 implementation that I came up with after heavily editing what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52465289/7487335) and in the [official documentation](https://www.python-ldap.org/en/latest/reference/ldap.html). At the time of writing this it works with the pip3 package [python-ldap](https://pypi.org/project/python-ldap/) version 3.2.0.

```
def get_list_of_ldap_users():
    hostname = "google.com"
    username = "username_here"
    password = "password_here"
    base = "dc=google,dc=com"

    print(f"Connecting to the LDAP server at '{hostname}'...")
    connect = ldap.initialize(f"ldap://{hostname}")
    connect.set_option(ldap.OPT_REFERRALS, 0)
    connect.simple_bind_s(username, password)
    connect=ldap_server
    search_flt = "(cn=demo_user*)" # get all users with a specific cn
    page_size = 1 # how many users to search for in each page, this depends on the server maximum setting (default is 1000)
    searchreq_attrlist=["cn", "sn", "name", "userPrincipalName"] # change these to the attributes you care about
    req_ctrl = SimplePagedResultsControl(criticality=True, size=page_size, cookie='')
    msgid = connect.search_ext_s(base=base, scope=ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filterstr=search_flt, attrlist=searchreq_attrlist, serverctrls=[req_ctrl])

    total_results = []
    pages = 0
    while True: # loop over all of the pages using the same cookie, otherwise the search will fail
        pages += 1
        rtype, rdata, rmsgid, serverctrls = connect.result3(msgid)
        for user in rdata:
            total_results.append(user)

        pctrls = [c for c in serverctrls if c.controlType == SimplePagedResultsControl.controlType]
        if pctrls:
            if pctrls[0].cookie: # Copy cookie from response control to request control
                req_ctrl.cookie = pctrls[0].cookie
                msgid = connect.search_ext_s(base=base, scope=ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, filterstr=search_flt, attrlist=searchreq_attrlist, serverctrls=[req_ctrl])
            else:
                break
        else:
            break
    return total_results
```